# Find files missing in one directory that are in a second - needs to ignore file extension

Tags: linux

I need to find files missing in one directory that are in a second, but I need to ignore file extensions. I need to do this based on file name only, not fill contents. If my file names were identical (including extensions), I could use diff something like:

```
diff dirA dirB
```

, however files in directory A have a different extension from those in directory B. I need a way to use something like diff but to ignore the extension differences between the two directories.

Another important point is that each directory may contain hundreds of thousands of files, so I have a need for a relatively efficient process.

Grateful for any ideas.

Comment: 1. `find` files in one directory and in the second directory. 2. `sort` both lists of files. 3. Use `comm` to compare them. `ignore the extension differences` 1.a) Use `sed` to remove extensions from both lists.

Comment: Have you thought of doing a copy of both dirs with different names like `test1` and `test2`, then remove all extensions of all files in both new dirs? Finally you could just start your diff as usual.

Comment: Thanks @woodz. The problem I have is that there are hundreds of thousands of files in each directory and they take up enormous amounts of disk space, so I cannot afford to copy them and then removing the extensions. I need a way to do it without replicating files.

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy: well OK, but I wonder what you are doing with those hundreds of thousands of diffs then effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helps

I created sample files, look like this
sample

/

├── a

│   ├── 1

│   └── 3

└── b

│   ├── 1

│   ├── 2

│   └── 3.txt

```
$comm -13 <(find a/ -type f -exec bash -c 'basename "${0%.*}"' {} \; | sort) <(find b/ -type f -exec bash -c 'basename "${0%.*}"' {} \; | sort)
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: thanks @Kerim, this worked for me once I changed "comm -13" to "comm -3". With the -1, I was getting nothing. Thanks so much!